# How can I express this max-min in CPLEX?

Tags: modeling, cplex, convex-optimization, minimax

Initially, I had the below objective function

$\max \sum_{u=1}^{U}\sum_{c=1}^{C}x_{u,c}d_{u,c}$

where $x_{u,c}$ are optimization variables

I modelled this in CPLEX as

```
   IloExpr  objFun (env); 
    for(int u = 0; u < U; u++){
          for(int c = 0; c < C; c++){
         objFun += x[u][c]* d[u][c];
        }
    }
    model.add(IloMaximize(env, objFun));  
    objFun.end();
```

Now, I have a slightly different objective

$\text{maximize} \min_{u} \sum_{c=1}^{C}x_{u,c}d_{u,c}$

Now how can I model this?

Answer (score 9):

You can model this as a maxmin problem by introducing an auxiliary variable $\theta$:

\begin{align}
\max&\quad\theta &\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad\theta \leq \sum_{c=1}^C x_{uc}d_{uc} & \forall u=1,\dots,U
\end{align}

For future reference, if in contrast you had a **minmax** objective instead of a **maxmin** objective, you could apply the same trick:
\begin{align}
\min&\quad\theta &\\
\text{s.t.}&\quad\theta \geq \sum_{c=1}^C x_{uc}d_{uc} & \forall u=1,\dots,U
\end{align}

Comment: Darn, Joris, you beat me by 27 seconds!

Answer (score 6):

Maximize an auxiliary variable $z$ subject to the constraints $z\le \sum_{c=1}^C d_{u,c}x_{u,c}\ \forall u$.